# WMIC and ECHO statements

Tags: batch-file, append, wmic

I'm trying to collect the list of programs from multiple computers and put them on one text file. When I use the below code I get a weird text instead of spaces and the computer name appended to my text file. The code and output from the code is below. The weird text is at the very start of the output, then a list of programs is appended. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
echo. >> C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\programs.txt
echo. >> C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\programs.txt
echo. >> C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\programs.txt
echo. >> C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\programs.txt
echo. >> C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\programs.txt
echo. >> C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\programs.txt
echo. >> C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\programs.txt
echo %computername% >> C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\programs.txt
wmic product get name,version >>"C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\programs.txt
```

Output:

ഠ ਍ഠ ਍ഠ ਍ഠ䨊剅奒倭⁃਍Name                                                      Version
VirtualDJ LE (Numark)                                                    7.0.5
Secure Download Manager                                                  3.1.60
Python 3.4.1 (64-bit)                                                    3.4.1150
Microsoft DCF MUI (English) 2013                                         15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013                                  15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft OneNote MUI (English) 2013                                     15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Office 32-bit Components 2013                                  15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Office Shared 32-bit MUI (English) 2013                        15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Office OSM MUI (English) 2013                                  15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Office OSM UX MUI (English) 2013                               15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft InfoPath MUI (English) 2013                                    15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Access MUI (English) 2013                                      15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Office Shared Setup Metadata MUI (English) 2013                15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Excel MUI (English) 2013                                       15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Access Setup Metadata MUI (English) 2013                       15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft PowerPoint MUI (English) 2013                                  15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Publisher MUI (English) 2013                                   15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Outlook MUI (English) 2013                                     15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Groove MUI (English) 2013                                      15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Word MUI (English) 2013                                        15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Lync MUI (English) 2013                                        15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Office Proofing (English) 2013                                 15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Office Shared MUI (English) 2013                               15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Office Proofing Tools 2013 - English                           15.0.4569.1506
Microsoft Office Proofing Tools 2013 - Español                           15.0.4569.1506
Outils de vérification linguistique 2013 de Microsoft Office - Français  15.0.4569.1506
Visual Studio 2008 x64 Redistributables                                  10.0.0.2
Visual Studio 2012 x64 Redistributables                                  14.0.0.1
WinZip 18.0                                                              18.0.10661
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219              10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64)                          8.0.61000
ActiveState Komodo IDE 8.5.3                                             8.5.3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899470/appending-in-a-windows-batch-script

Comment: the weird text appears to be you computer's name

Comment: @Monacraft My Computer's name is 'Jerry-PC'

Comment: @sachadee Your link answered my question

Answer (score 0):

You are adding empty lines in your text file by using

```
echo. >> C:\Users\Jerry\Desktop\programs.txt
```

Why ? But if you can ignore the spaces and that the computer name comes on the first line you can use this solution.

And the output format of wmic is strange it is full of empty lines and null values and spaces. The best thing is to do it a little bit different by specifying the format and output file.

This will make the wmic output work on "foreign systems" (cmd line and non latin ascii stuff sucks)

```
wmic /output:C:\temp\programs.txt product get name,version /format:csv
```

or

```
wmic /output:C:\temp\programs_%computername%.txt product get name,version /format:csv
```

Which will give you a file with the computer name.

That the computer name is garbled looks like your on a non American system.

You can play with the code pages for cmd line or just create a text file put in your spaces save it. Then in cmd line copy the file and then output to that file. In some configurations you get out of allot of hassle by using that method because you get the correct BOM header and encoding.

For more info look at: [Kung Fu with WMIC](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Windows+Command-Line+Kung+Fu+with+WMIC/1229)  Which has good hints and tips and for the format look at this [article](http://www.pearsonitcertification.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1700427&seqNum=4)